# Leaflet markers based on database attributes

Tags: leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet and I want to work with **attribute based marker icons**. I followed a couple of tutorials and can display markers on my screen using geometry data from a PostGIS database.

```js
var mapDataLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: "#F00",
            color: "#FFF",
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            opacity: 0.8,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var html = "";
        for (prop in feature.properties){
            html += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
        };
        layer.bindPopup(html);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Using this, I get a couple of points with the same color. Now I want to split up these points using different colors/icons for different attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a look at feature.properties[prop]

I created a function to give the attributes "status" one out of five colors:

```
function getColor(status) {
return  status == "proposed"     ? '#800888' :
        status == "permitted"    ? '#969696' :
        status == "operational"  ? '#081d58' :
        status == "development"  ? '#006837' :
        status == "denied"       ? '#fed976' :
                                   '#252525';
}
```

Then i edited the code above a bit to include the getColor function.

```
    var mapDataLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.status),
            color: "#FFF",
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            opacity: 0.8,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var html = "";
        for (prop in feature.properties){
            html += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
        };
        layer.bindPopup(html);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: That's it, forgot about the multiple = operator, thanks a lot ghybs

Answer (score 1):

You would probably simply need to follow an extra tutorial for custom markers: [Markers With Custom Icons](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html)

> In this tutorial, you’ll learn how to easily define your own icons for use by the markers you put on the map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ghybs, i've seen that tutorial but it doesn't say anything about retrieving attributes from the database.

Comment: By "attributes", what do you mean then? Are not they accessible through `feature.properties[prop]`?

Comment: By attributes i mean attributes from the databases, in this case "status" or "county".